# ¿Cuál sería la traducción correcta para "bountied"?

Tags: traducción, solicitud-de-término, vocabulario-técnico, español-neutral

Hoy hubo un cambio dentro de Stack Exchange, donde la categoría *Featured* pasó a ser *Bountied*.

La traducción de 'bounty' es *recompensa*. Sin embargo, dependendiendo del contexto, no hay una traducción para *bountied*, que no sea algo como:

- con recompensas

Viendo cómo cambió esa pestaña dentro de la estructura del sitio, me pregunto si no habrá una traducción mejor que no implique el uso de una conjunción para describir a las preguntas.

La idea de usar la palabra *recompensadas* no suena cómoda en español para describir a preguntas que tienen una recompensa activa, porque suena a que las mismas ya recibieron una recompensa.

La palabra *Bountied* se encuentra entre las pestañas de las preguntas del sitio de [Stack Overflow en español](https://es.stackoverflow.com/); actualmente se visualiza de la siguiente forma:

> [image]

Comment: Creo que el título debería cambiarse para reflejar todas los requisitos exigidos. Todas las respuestas aquí dadas son traducciones correctas pero ninguna es marcada como aceptada.

Comment: @cdlvcdlv no hay requisitos, mas que quede bien. No acepte ninguna respuesta, porque pienso que podemos llegar a tener un poco mas de votos en alguna respuesta que incline la balanza. Debo acepar una respuesta casi inmediatamente? todas son validas (casi todas!!! algunas suenan medio raro).

Comment: Nunca me ha gustado el uso de bounty en inglés en este sitio utilizado como verbo. La verdad es que es feíssimo en inglés. Deberian decir: questions with a bounty. Bounty question. Bountified no está bien por nada.

Comment: @Lambie What do you think about translating in English the suggested "Se busca": "Wanted"? I like both best than "Bountied/Recompensadas".

Comment: @RubioRic What do you mean translate? It's already in English. Se busca is for criminals (bounty hunter). That is the wrong meaning here.

Comment: @RubioRic But you said: What do you think about translating **in[to] English** the suggested "Se busca": Bountied is not se busca. And the verb in English is a mistake.

Comment: @Lambie Well, maybe I lost my track. I like the concept of "Se busca". You have mentioned "bounty hunters" and those questions are already labeled "bountied" in English. They are not so far away. "If you're looking for a bounty, this is your place, click the link"

Comment: @RubioRic "This question has an open **bounty** worth +50 reputation from [name removed]

Comment: @Lambie Yes, I know the term in relation with SE. "Se busca respuesta. Recompensa +50" It sounds well to me. (Not trying to translate your text, just representing the concept in Spanish)

Comment: Que tal: preguntas `ardientes` o `candentes`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yo optaría por:

> Con recompensa

Es la frase más corta, me parece, que indica que la pregunta tiene una recompensa activa y que no haya sido ya entregada.

Comment: la duda que me da con este titulo es que ya existen recompensas entregadas, y solo se veran las recompensas activas que no se han entregado

Comment: Es que hay preguntas con recompensas entragadas, pero no hay filtro para eso

Comment: Es lo que muestra ese tab, solo las que tienen recompensas activas. @JackNavaRow

Comment: se que muestra las activas, pero suena a que puedo ver todas las recompensas , tal vez este exagerando yo

Comment: Sí pero ese mismo "problema" (aunque no lo considero como tal) tiene la frase en inglés

Comment: realizando pruebas, [cuando busco una pregunta, y no hay recompensas activa el tab se oculta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/search?tab=relevance&q=Json%20y%20objeto)

Answer (score 7):

Voy por: pregunta "premiada", dado que el premio va desde 50 puntos de reputación.

También pensé pregunta "desesperada", la gran mayoría buscan una respuesta a toda costa.

La traducción literal sería "recompensada", suena muy largo y me parece que en el buen español es una palabra inexistente.

Comment: Recompensada me suena a que ya tiene una recompensa entregada. Lo mismo para premiada

Comment: Me gustó tu sugerencia de «pregunta desesperada», muy divertida :) Como traductor profesional, aprecio cuando la gente se esfuerza por transmitir un significado preciso en función de dónde se utilizará el término. Gracias por ir más allá de lo literal.

Comment: hahaha xD!!! gracias a ti por comentar :D

Comment: @fredyfx por qué dices que "recompensada" es una palabra inexistente?

Comment: >> me parece << no estoy del todo seguro :D

Comment: "Toda buena acción debe ser recompensada" me parece un buen uso del español. :-) Otra cosa es que encaje o no dentro de lo que se pretende expresar.

Comment: El verbo en inglés (bountied) es un error de inglés. Questions on SE have a bounty. Nada más. Y premio funciona. Las otras ideas no. Se busca no funciona. No pondría un verbo.

Comment: Muchas gracias @Charlie tienes razón :D

Answer (score 6):

Por salir un poco de la línea de traducciones cuasi-literales, propongo:

**Se busca**

Es la locución empleada tradicionalmente en los [carteles que ofrecen recompensas](https://www.google.com/search?q=se%20busca&tbm=isch) por entregar a un/a criminal.

Podría usarse, de manera desenfadada, para indicar preguntas que ofrecen recompensa por responderlas :)

Comment: +1 porque yo tuve la misma idea, aunque no sé por qué no me terminaba de cuadrar, pero viendo que no soy el único al que se le ha ocurrido bien podríamos darle una oportunidad.

Comment: La mejor en mi opinión, quizás los western hayan influido en nosotros ;-P

Comment: me gusta esta idea y le da mas frescura a la traduccion, sobre todo porque no es literal... y al fin y al cabo, cuando se daba una recompensa, el cartel dice eso...

Answer (score 3):

Las locuciones «con recompensa» y «con gratificación» suenan bien y no son demasiado largas; no deberían causar afectaciones a la interfaz de StackExchange:
[image: Bosquejo de cómo quedaría el término]

Pero dado que buscas una traducción que sea univerbal, es posible también recurrir a un sufijo que denote el significado ‘susceptible de recibir *x*’, y ese es *-ble*: así, obtenemos «**gratificable**», por ejemplo. Por supuesto, este término suena mucho más formal que el original en inglés, así que *caveat emptor*.

Comment: seria gratificables? pero me cuesta entender exactamente que quiere decir... igual todo aporte es mas que bienvenido mil gracias!!!!

Comment: Como ya indiqué en la respuesta, el significado de «gratificable» literalmente es ‘propenso/susceptible de recibir gratificación’.

Comment: Me exprese mal.. creo que me cuesta entenderlo en el concepto de una pregunta.. y lo otro es si no seria gratificables.. ya que es una lista de preguntas.

Comment: Sí, por supuesto; el término univerbal debería ir en plural por referirse a varias preguntas… Acabo de añadir una imagen de cómo yo dejaría los nombres de las pestañas si StackExchange me hubiera hecho el encargo :)

Comment: las traducciones sobre el sitio son comunitarias.. siempre se acepta ayuda :)

Answer (score 2):

Propongo una pequeña adaptación:

- **Premios**

O si prefieres:

- **Premio**

Me parece importante que sea una sola palabra, y que sea algo sencillo y corto.

---

*Extra text to prevent automatic VLC flagging.* Bla bla.  Sometimes short is good but computer programs don't know how to distinguish.

Comment: This is being flagged by the system as low quality, perhaps a  comment? And is this really a translation for bountied? I would have thought it was for bounty.

Comment: @mdewey - It is an *adaptation*.  Sometimes what is needed is a word or phrase that conveys a concept, without being strictly faithful to the part of speech of the original.

Comment: Do you happen to know if this use of bounty is elsewhere around here? I find it to be truly awful.

Comment: @Lambie - I didn't understand what you find awful.  "Bounty"?  "Bountied"? "Premios"?

Comment: bountied. It isn't really a word today. The OED has only one entry and here it is: **1788**   T. Jefferson Writings (1859) II. 524   The eighty-five ships..bountied as the English are, will require a sacrifice of twelve hundred and eighty-five thousand livres a year.

Comment: @Lambie - I agree, I don't like *bounty* as a verb; I think somebody waved a magic wand and said, "Hey presto!  *Bounty* is now a verb!"

Comment: Why is it even in the en español section anyway? Gees....:)

Comment: @Lambie - I don't get it.  This was an across-the-board change.  I see at at ELU, for example.

Answer (score 1):

Pues voy a proponer "Devengables".

> #### [devengar](https://dle.rae.es/?id=DbVCUjJ)
>
> De *de-* y el lat. *vindicāre* 'atribuirse, apropiarse'.
>
> **1.** [tr.](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/a/31179/12991) Adquirir derecho a alguna percepción o retribución por
>   razón de trabajo, servicio u otro título. *Devengar salarios, costas,
>   intereses.*

(Invito al lector a pasar el puntero por encima de "tr.").

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/97513/discussion-on-answer-by-cdlvcdlv-cual-seria-la-traduccion-correcta-para-bountie).

Answer (score 1):

Yo estoy totalmente a favor de "**Se busca**", la sugerencia de walen.
Entiendo que no tratamos de encontrar un traducción literal. Considero que refleja perfectamente el concepto - Se busca respuesta, se ofrece recompensa - y puede resultar más atrayente para el usuario. Incluso abogaría por aplicarlo en los sitios en inglés: **wanted**. Mucho mejor que el término inventado "bountied".

Dicho esto permitidme que añada un sugerencia nueva que creo no se ha mencionado aún: **bonificadas**.

**[bonificar](https://dle.rae.es/?id=5rEW7YT)**

> 2. tr. **Conceder a alguien, por algún concepto, un aumento**, generalmente proporcional y reducido, **en una cantidad que ha de
>      cobrar**, o un descuento en la que ha de pagar.

La respuesta aceptada supone la concesión de los puntos correspondientes ("la cantidad que ha de cobrar") más la recompensa ofrecida ("un aumento").

Answer (score 0):

Se me ocurren los términos *[recompensable](http://dle.rae.es/?id=VTlj0Iw)* (que se puede recompensar), *[remunerable](http://dle.rae.es/?id=Vvy6HiR)* (que se puede recompensar, premiar o galardonar), *[retribuible](http://dle.rae.es/?id=WKMS0Si)* (que se puede retribuir, recompensar), usando el sufijo *[-ble](http://dle.rae.es/?id=5gagNwr)* que indica la posibilidad pasiva de que tenga lugar la acción indicada.

Y dado que se están proponiendo alternativas ocurrentes, propongo yo la mía (aunque tal vez quede un poco larga): ***Las más deseadas***.

Comment: @walen me di cuenta después de publicarla, de hecho he votado la otra respuesta. Pensé en borrarla, pero como he propuesto nuevas opciones pues tampoco pasa nada por dejarla.

Answer (score 0):

Creo que lo más simple es lo mejor:

**recompensable**: 1. adj. Que se puede recompensar. 2. adj. Digno de recompensa.

**recompensado**: de recompensar. 1. tr. Compensar el daño hecho. 2. tr. Retribuir o remunerar un servicio.